# How to read an array inside an array in JSON using python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I am trying to read the "transcript" from my json file and i just can't get inside it. I can access the main JSON but not the specific part of it.

My JSON file

```
    "results": [ {
      "alternatives": [ {
        "confidence": 0.90822744,
        "transcript":"bunch of words" ,
        "words": [ {
          "endTime": "1.400s",
          "startTime": "0s",
          "word": "bunch"
        },...
```

My Code snippet

```
f =  open('C:\\Users\\Kerem\\Desktop\\YeniGoogleapi\\MugeAnliileTatliSert7Kasim.json', encoding="utf8")
data = json.load(f)

for i in data['results']:
  print(i)
```

Comment: `i['alternatives'][0]['transcript']`. Or iterate over `i['alternatives']`

Comment: Thank you @YevhenKuzmovych it worked! Why do we put [0] between them?

Comment: Because `i['alternatives']` is a list, you either index it or iterate over it